# Displaying from which git commit a binary was compiled

Tags: git, makefile, autotools

I'm using autotools and git in a C/C++ program.

I would like my program to be able to show from which commit it was compiled. For example it would show:

```
$ myprog --version
Binary compiled from commit 9ddb505
```

In bash, it's easy to determine the current commit:

```
COMMIT=$(git log -1 --pretty='%h')
```

But this syntax is not valid inside a Makefile.am file.

Let's say I have a very simple Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = myprog
myprog_SOURCES = main.c
myprog_CPPFLAGS = -Wall -DGIT_COMMIT=\"??SOMETHING??\"
```

How can I pass the right commit value to my source, considering that the commit name must be up-to-date on each call of `make`?

---

#### EDIT

I tried also (in Makefile.am):

```
COMMIT=\"$(shell git log -1 --pretty='%h')\"
```

But this syntax generate an error with automake:

> src/Makefile.am:3: warning: shell git log -1 --pretty='%h': non-POSIX
>   variable name src/Makefile.am:3: (probably a GNU make extension)

, and it's colored in red with Vim's syntax (filetype=automake).

The solution would be to pass directly this line to be included in the final Makefile, but how can I do this in Makefile.am? I tried to escape the `$` sign, with no success.

Comment: 1. Tag releases 2. For tagged DAG `git describe` will be prettier

Comment: By the way, you get the same result very much more directly with `git rev-parse @`. Purely aesthetics, so season to taste.

Comment: [Mercurial's makefile](https://bitbucket.org/follower/hgversion-handling/src/51c22e5cef6deb3005bd86584229b5c7d1a80185/Makefile?fileviewer=file-view-default) for autotools, can be easy adopted for Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
GITVERSION:= $(shell git log -1 --pretty='%h')
```

to your Makefile and

```
-DGITVERSION="\"${GITVERSION}\""
```

to your CPPFLAGS and you can use GITVERSION inside code

Comment: It's not working, because I'm working with an automake Makefile.am, see my edit

Comment: @yolenoyer - 1) try use `git describe` 2) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196236/looking-for-a-way-to-store-versions-in-a-binary-compiled-from-git-repo for ideas

Comment: Ok, it's working : I didn't realize in my edit, that is was only a warning. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think for you the missing link appears to be the shell cmd in Make.

You can do in your Makefile:

```
GIT_MSG=\"$(shell git log -1 --pretty='%h')\"
CFLAGS=-Wall -DGIT_COMMIT=$(GIT_MSG)
```

Then use `GIT_COMMIT` as a macro in your C/C++ source files.

P.s.:

Use the following for something like `master-1399ff4`:

```
GIT_MSG=\"$(shell echo "`git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | cut -b 12-`-`git log --pretty=format:\"%h\" -1`, ")\"
```

And use `git describe` to print tags if your git repo has any.

Comment: It doesn't work because I'm working with an automake Makefile.am, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Makefile.am

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = -DGIT_VERSION="\"$(shell git log -1 --pretty='%h')\""
```

You will still get the warning

```
Makefile.am:14: warning: shell git log -1 --pretty='%h': non-POSIX variable name
Makefile.am:14: (probably a GNU make extension)
```

Make it disappear with:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(-Wno-portability)
```

in configure.am